# Mongodb can't connect to localhost but can connect to localhost's IP address

Tags: mongodb, localhost

If I try to run mongodb shell with the `mongo` command alone, I get:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
```

exception: connect failed

However, if I stipulate localhost's LAN IP address like this:

```
mongo 10.10.5.90
```

...it connects fine.

Any clues??

Comment: yes I can ping 127 and localhost

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you have a `bind_ip` set in your mongodb.conf (or startup script)? **edit for clarity** A `bind_ip` setting limits the IP it will listen on to that IP only.

See the IP Address Binding section: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication

If not, do you have any firewall rules blocking the localhost access? That would be kind of strange, but I can't think of another reason why it wouldn't work while the LAN IP would work.

Comment: Here's my mongodb.conf:  bind_ip = 10.10.5.90
port = 27017
dbpath = /data/db
logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend = true
vvvv = true
journal = true
rest = true

Comment: Take out the bind_ip setting if you want to be able to connect from localhost also. See the doc I linked.

Comment: Wes, thank you.  Removing the bind_ip setting fixed the issue.

Comment: You should be able to list multiple addresses for bind_ip (comma separated). Not working for me.

Comment: Where can I find my mongodb.conf?

Comment: @Solace this is fully up to you. Usually you put it at `/etc/mongodb.conf`. When you start the service, then you must provide the config file, e.g. `mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf` otherwise is uses default settings.

Comment: How can a firewall block the localhost access?

Answer (score 11):

This error could also appear if mongodb was not properly shutdown. If you type `sudo start mongodb` and if it gives a new process id on every execution then your mongodb was not properly shutdown. To resolve this type

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair 
sudo start mongodb
```

Answer (score 9):

**Just follow all these steps to solve this problem**

```
Step 1: Remove lock file.
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

Step 2: Repair mongodb.
mongod --repair 

Step 3: start mongodb.
sudo start mongodb 
or
sudo service mongodb start

Step 4: Check status of mongodb.
sudo status mongodb 
or   
sudo service mongodb status

Step 5: Start mongo console.
mongo
```

Comment: service name for mongodb in ubuntu is mongod not mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I prefer configuration

```
net:
  bindIpAll: true
```

or

```
net:
  bindIp: localhost
```

The upper configuration allows connections from remote computers (unless blocked by firewall), the second one allows only connections from your local machine.

In my opinion, configuration like

```
net:
  bindIp: 10.10.5.90
```

makes only sense on a computer with multiple network interfaces.

Note, meanwhile we are in 2023, it makes sense to add

```
net:
  ipv6: true
```

or `mongod --ipv6 ...` because IPv6 is disabled by default, but IPv6 is getting more and more common.

Answer (score 0):

I added localhost along with the ip I had in bind_ip while starting mongo and it solved my problem, for example:
bin/mongod --dbpath data --logpath mongo.log --fork --bind_ip localhost,10.100.1.2

Answer (score 0):

For people using MongoDB Compass on VMWare windows:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin by default is the Mongo server directory. You can change bindIp and port in mongod.cfg

Also make sure to check if the mongo server service is running:
win + r > services.msc > MongoDB Server (MongoDB) > Rightclick > Start.

Should save some time, hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Edit your mongod.conf as follow

**bindIp: 0.0.0.0,localhost**

It works for me.