# Repair Mongodb using ruby-mongodb-driver

Tags: mongodb

Is there an API know to anyone to repair mongodb is case of corrupt databases through ruby-mongodb-driver.

Looking through the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.6.2/)  seem that there isn't

can anyone confirm.

Or can anyone suggest me a better way to repair mongod database .

the currently I knew

```
./mongod --repair options

./mongo

> use [database]
> db.repairDatabase()
```

I also see a shell options

```
 ./mongo --help 

options:
  --shell               run the shell after executing files
```

How can I write a script(.js) to repair the given database

Comment: I find `db.repairDatabase()` most convenient. Can't you do it?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904991/mongodb-cant-connect-to-localhost-but-can-connect-to-localhosts-ip-address/8905337#8905337) answer.

Comment: @benchwarmer I knew that all I want is better way to running  code from a ruby program thank any way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the mongo shell, the database name can be given as an optional argument.  Here is a shell script that should make this clear.

repair.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then    echo "$0 - repair mongodb database"
        echo "usage: $0 database-name"
        exit 1
fi
mongo $1 --eval 'printjson(db.repairDatabase())'
```

Here is a ruby 1.9 equivalent.

repair.rb

```
#!/bin/env ruby
require 'mongo'
if ARGV.length < 1
    puts "$0 - repair mongodb database"
    puts "usage: $0 database-name"
    exit 1
end
db = Mongo::Connection.new[ARGV[0]]
puts db.command({repairDatabase: 1})
```

There's more info in the FAQ and documentation for DB.

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.FAQ.html

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/DB.html

Navigation to some documentation isn't obvious - we'll look into making it better.

Comment: Is it Mongo::Connection.new(ARGV[0]) or Mongo::Connection.new.db(ARGV[0])