# mongodb via mongoVUE connection refused

Tags: mongodb, connection, mongovue

Trying to connect to remote mongodb via mongoVUE (windows 7)

Cannot do that - always have a response "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

firewall is off..

Anybody had such an issue?

Comment: I'd start by checking whether the server is listening on the correct ports: assuming that your Mongo server is a Linux machine and that you have access, can you add what the output of `netstat -l | grep 27017` is?   If it's a Windows machine, run `netstat -a` and find a line that has state `LISTENING` and a local address column that ends in `:27017`.  In both cases it should be listening on either 0.0.0.0 or the ip address you're talking to.

Comment: but if i currently do not have access to server machine..?

Comment: Well in that case you're out of luck.  As the server *actively* refuses your connection it's aware you're trying to talk with it, so the next thing would be to figure out why it doesn't seem willing to let you talk with Mongo, and what I proposed was a first in finding the reason of that....

Comment: seems it's something with my local machine.. cause from another one it's possible connect, but firewall is off that's a pitty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Mongo instance you are trying to connect to is part of a replica set you should try to pass in the whole set comma separated into the Server field of the connection

I had exactly the same issue and this was the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, from [Mongodb can't connect to localhost but can connect to localhost's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904991/mongodb-cant-connect-to-localhost-but-can-connect-to-localhosts-ip-address):

> Do you have a bind_ip set in your mongodb.conf (or startup script)? A bind_ip setting limits the IP it will listen on to that IP only.
>
> See the IP Address Binding section: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication

Comment out the bind_ip setting in mongodb.conf, restart mongod and you should be able to connect.