# [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]] from NodeJS to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having problem connecting to MongoDB from NodeJS using following sample code. I tried running "mongod" with or without sudo but nodejs code still fail to connect. I am able to successfully connect to database using "mongo".

Running on  : MAC OS 10.6.8

```
   var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(error, db) {
        if(!error){
             console.log("We are connected");
        }
        else
           console.dir(error);
    });
```

get following error running above code : [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]

Also tried mongoose but similar error:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function callback () {
          console.log("DB connected");
    // yay!
    });
```

Output:   connection error: [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]

Here is the log of mongod

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-07-11T23:33:47.843-0700 kern.sched unavailable
2014-07-11T23:33:47.849-0700 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=29942 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=usc8bcc8a0d0b1
2014-07-11T23:33:47.849-0700 [initandlisten]
2014-07-11T23:33:47.849-0700 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2014-07-11T23:33:47.849-0700 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.3
2014-07-11T23:33:47.849-0700 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2014-07-11T23:33:47.849-0700 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin usc8bcc8a0d0b1 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-07-11T23:33:47.849-0700 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2014-07-11T23:33:47.849-0700 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-07-11T23:33:47.850-0700 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-07-11T23:33:47.850-0700 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-07-11T23:33:47.901-0700 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-07-11T23:34:47.901-0700 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:48 virt:2810
2014-07-11T23:34:47.901-0700 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):320
2014-07-11T23:34:47.901-0700 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Answer (score 22):

Never mind, I was able to resolve the issue by using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, not sure why I have to use ip address. My tomcat, apache, redis, and even node server all works using localhost but not the mongodb. Is there is config I need change to make it work using local host?

Comment: YES! I used 127.0.0.1 in my apache config, which was previously localhost and it connected instantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` in `/private/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I commented "127.0.0.1 localhost" in my hosts file.

Comment: Line `127.0.0.1 localhost` should exist in every `/etc/hosts` file by default. Unless you messed up your system, this answer is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

- This issue can occur if your mongoDBwasnot shutdown properly 
  [Mongodb can't connect to localhost but can connect to localhost's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904991/mongodb-cant-connect-to-localhost-but-can-connect-to-localhosts-ip-address)
- Start your mongoDB Server using follwoingcommand and then try same                       `./mongod --bind_ip localhost`

Comment: This works, but then you can connect only from your local machine. This might be your intention or not.

Answer (score 1):

yes , I came across this error too, and my hosts is as follow:

`127.0.0.1 xxxxxx(the ip of my computer)`

and when I ran `npm start` in express project, it got an error like that . After I tried to change the mapping of `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`, it had no error.

Comment: It should be the other way around. Format of `/etc/hosts` file is `IPAddress Hostname Alias`. "the ip of my computer" is the (real) IP address, it should not be the alias. Typically you have `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `<the ip of my computer> <computer name>`

Answer (score -1):

Somebody on Github found a solution:
Instead of writing:

```
Mongoose.connect(config.database.url);
```

Write:

```
Mongoose.connect(config.database.url, {
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

(Source https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399)