# MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my db.js:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
export default () => {
 mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meetupapp');
 mongoose.connection
     .once('open', () => console.log('Mongodb running'))
    .on('error', err => console.error(err));
};
```

and this is the error message: MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect]
  name: 'MongoError

I've installed mongodb!

Comment: Did you start "mongod"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[Error: failed to connect to \[localhost:27017\]\] from NodeJS to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710490/error-failed-to-connect-to-localhost27017-from-nodejs-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Verify your mongodb engine is running or not

### WINDOWS

1.) Open command prompt
2.) Type mongo

if it works that means mongod is running or else you have to start it manually

### COMMAND

```
mongod --dbpath [path-of-your-database]
```

create folder where you want to store the database and assign that folderpath in --dbpath

Ex "c:/mongo/db/"

and then try mongo command and it will work..

### LINUX

### COMMAND

```
1.) sudo service mongod start
```

### MAC

After installing mongodb

### COMMAND

```
1.) export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH  [Setting the environment variable]
2.) mkdir -p /data/db   [creating directory for data to store]
3.) mongod --dbpath [path-of-your-database]
```