# Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Node.js driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, localhost, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I have just started learning about MongoDB and I am trying to host my Node.js application locally via MongoDB Server 6.0 (without using [Mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_%28web_server%29) or [Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB#MongoDB_Atlas)).

I copied the async JavaScript code given in the MongoDB documentation. I made sure to run **mongod** before executing the below code:

MongoDB server started
[image: MongoDB server started]

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Connection URI
const uri =
  "**mongodb://localhost:27017**";

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();

    // Establish and verify connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

**It's throwing an error:**

[image: Image of the error it's throwing]

Comment: What happens if you use `const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";`?

Comment: Are you running from windows ?? Can you start mongob from services of windows and then retry

Comment: It worked! 
I did both. First, restarted mongodb from services and changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and It connected successfully. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem is, the `localhost` alias resolves to IPv6 address `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`

However, [`net.ipv6`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.ipv6) defaults to `false`.

The best option would be to start the MongoDB with this configuration:

```
net:
  ipv6: true
  bindIpAll: true
```

or

```
net:
  ipv6: true
  bindIp: localhost
```

Then all variants will work:

```
C:\>mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017" --quiet --eval "db.getMongo()"
mongodb://localhost:27017/?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.6.0

C:\>mongosh "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" --quiet --eval "db.getMongo()"
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.6.0

C:\>mongosh "mongodb://[::1]:27017" --quiet --eval "db.getMongo()"
mongodb://[::1]:27017/?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.6.0

C:\>mongosh "mongodb://%COMPUTERNAME%:27017" --quiet --eval "db.getMongo()"
$ mongosh "mongodb://$HOSTNAME:27017" --quiet --eval "db.getMongo()"
mongodb://******:27017/?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.6.0
```

If you don't run MongoDB as a service then it would be

```
mongod --bind_ip_all --ipv6 <other options>
```

NB, I don't like configuration

```
net:
  bindIp: <ip_address>
```

In my opinion this  makes only sense on a computer with multiple network interfaces. However, since MongoDB [does not support multiple interfaces](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1889) it does not make much sense either.
Also depending on your network settings, this IP may change at any time.

Use `bindIp: localhost` if you like to permit connections only from the local machine, e.g. while maintenance or when used as backend database for a web-service. Use `bindIpAll: true` if you like to permit connections also from remote machines.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that I couldn't find this in the official docs, but I did find it here. After trying many things, your "best option" above worked for me.

Comment: It is rather an issue of the operating system than a problem with MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you are using the node version 18(Ig it also works for 17)

```html
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/newdb", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", () => console.log("error connecting to database"));

db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to database"));
```

Comment: `"error connecting to database"`  is a rather poor error message. Better print the real error, e.g. `db.on("error", (err) => console.log("error connecting to database: " + err.message));` or even better the full error stack

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is, the localhost alias resolves to IPv6 address ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1

From `@Wernfried Domscheit` Answer above. The summary for me

I just replace `mongodb://localhost/dbName` with `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbName` and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017").then(() => {
  console.log("database connected)).catch((err) => {
  console.log("error while connecting to database")
})
```

Comment: I don't think IP `0.0.0.0`  will work, usually it means "**any** IP-Address". Apart from that, you should always print proper error instead of static text `"error while connecting to database"` which does not provide any information.