# MongoDB connection problems

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I am trying to connect MongoDB with node.js but whenever I try I am getting this error. (MongoDB is started).

[[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj9Sk.png)][JavaScript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKFRk.png)

I tried to restart MongoDB.

Comment: Don't post code as images.  Post it as text and use the proper code markdown formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by replacing the URI from (mongodb://localhost:27017) to
(mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017).

And it worked for me.

Comment: I don't think that's a proper solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881

Comment: Agree with you, but it worked for me.