# Node Js , MongoDb " error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have used MongoDb and Node Js before, unfortunately after reinstalling the two which is after formatting the laptop, connecting the database to Node Js seemingly is not working.
Below is my code

codeimage for the code

[image: 1]

Output

[image: 2]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: You connect to `localhost` which is an alias for `::1`, this is a IP version 6 address. By default IPv6 is not enabled in MongoDB, set `net.ipv6: true` in config file or option `--ipv6`

Comment: If it does not work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881

Answer (score 1):

With regards to MongoDB update, instead of using 'localhost' one is required to use '127.0.0.1'.

Example instead of: `mongodb://localhost:27017/Company`, one is supposed to write it as; `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Company`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem but now I'm using following code and is working for me

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('./app');
const DB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Tour-project'

mongoose.connect(DB, (err) => {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err.name, err.message); // display the cause of error for database conenction
      console.error('Error during mongoDB connection');
      console.log('UNHANDLED REJECTION!! ‍♂️‍♂️ ');
   } else {
      // console.log(mongoose.connections);
      console.log('MongoDB connected successfully');
   }
});
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, 'localhost', () => {
   console.log(`Server is running using port number: ${port}`);
   console.log(`app listening on endpoint ${port}`);
});
```