# how to correct the mongodb error i get here

Tags: mongodb

```
D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:698
          throw error;
          ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Database instance at:
    at D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\lib\database.js:36:16
    at D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:695:9
    at D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:285:23
    at connectCallback (D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:367:5)
    at D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:554:14
    at Object.connectHandler [as callback] (D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:286:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Others\HTML\login node\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:443:25)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
          name: 'MongoNetworkError'
        },
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 157429114,
        lastWriteDate: null,
        opTime: null,
        type: 'Unknown',
        topologyVersion: undefined,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: []
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

im new and i havent tried much
i encounter this error whenever i try to psot details into the login page
details are being forwarded through the localhost to the node server but the mongodb database is throwing error

how to correct this error anyone help

whats this error what does this even mean

Comment: It means you can't connect to your mongo server. You'll need to provide more details about where that server is and how it can be accessed.

Comment: No idea why this question has been closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881

Comment: @deceze The question is certainly not perfect but when you are familiar with MongoDB then you see in provided error messages immediately where the problem is and you can give an answer.