# Connecting MongoDb with node for the very first time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I'm connecting mongodb with node js and getting such error

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825:32)
    at C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:419:10
    at C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1272:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:418:20)
    at connect_db (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\db.js:5:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\app.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Comment: How do you connect? What is the connection string?

Comment: I think it is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881