# Unable to Connect to the MongoDB Database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Using the MongoDb and Mongoose for the first time to store the data of my app.js file. When I run the app.js then it throws this error after a while -> MongooseError: Operation `peoples.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/peopleDB",
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("MongoDB is connected");
  }
);

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
});

const People = new mongoose.model("People", peopleSchema);

const people = new People({ name: "John", age: 37 });

people.save();
```

[this is the code that I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7poZr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching for the solution got to know that the connection was not made, if you are using the node the latest node.js version then replace the "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" and then try running the app.js

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881

Comment: `localhost` is an alias for IP 127.0.0.1, so either should work. However, on newer operating system `localhost` resolves to IPv6 `::1` and mongod does not bind to IPv6 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Create model name as "person", since people is already plural, and it may cause an error.
And make sure you run mongod server in the background using git

Comment: thanks for answering, yes I did run mongod server in the background using git.