# Can no longer connect to local mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mac and I usually run mongodb using

```
mongod --dbpath=/Users/username/data/db
```

I also connect to my local db using MongoDB Compass.
I install `mongosh` through brew cause I need to load a script using

```
load('scripts/script.js')
```

Inside the script, I connect using

```
db = connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&ssl=false&directConnection=true"
```

);

Everything was running fine. Then I need to cleanup my collections so I drop my collections using the MongoDB compass.

I then run `mongosh` so I can load the script.  This time, I got the following error

```
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:2701
```

I tried deleting `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` but still cannot connect.
I closed my VSCode where I use to run commands in terminal and reopen and still cannot connect.
I restarted my laptop and start `mongod` and run `mongosh` and load the script, still got the error mentioned.  But I am still able to connect through Mongodb Compass.

Comment: Ho do you connect? Maybe your problem is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881

Comment: i updated the question, added the way i connect in the script which was working before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the version of Node.js recently?
If so checkout this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-4538