# Node server stucks at starting when listen function is inside the mongoDB connectToServer() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect my mongodb server with express. But the server is not listening when i am giving the listen function inside connectToServer(). The following snippet is the index.js file.

```
const express = require("express");
const { connectToServer } = require("./utils/dbConnect");
const usersRoute=require('./routes/users.route.js');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
connectToServer((err) => {
 
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log({ port });
    }
    
)});
app.use('/users',usersRoute)
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});
```

Here is the dbConnect.js snippet:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

let dbConnection;

module.exports = {
  connectToServer: function (callback) {
    client.connect(function (err, db) {
      if (err || !db) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      dbConnection = db.db("users");
      console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");

      return callback();
    });
  },

  getDb: function () {
    return dbConnection;
  },
};
```

The server stucks at **[nodemon] starting `node index.js`**

I was expecting to get the server running and listening. But it doesn't.

Comment: Can you connect to the local mongod using mongosh or compass?

Comment: This would appear to be more of a "mongo is not listening where I expect" issue than a "my code cannot connect to mongo" issue.  Perhaps we should inspect the mongo config?

Comment: @Joe yes. compass connection is working seamlessly and i can do commands on mongosh shell. it just not working with node.js

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means the operating system actively refused the connection because nothing is listening on that port.  In the sample error message, it looks like it is trying with the IPv6 localhost.  Is the error message different when using 127.0.0.1 in the connection string?

Comment: If i set the connectionString to mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017, the console window stucks at [nodemon] starting `node index.js` forever. But no error message

Comment: Isn't that what it should do?  Is it listening on port 5000?

Comment: Yes. The server port is 5000. But it is not listening. i can't see this line output. console.log({ port });

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit now the server is not crushing. But it’s still not listening.

Comment: Do you still get the same error? I don't think so, in this case you may open a new question or at least edit your question and update with latest error message.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit there is no error now. Just the server is stuck at starting. The console log inside the listen function is not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the dbConnect() snippet.

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb-legacy");
const connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

let dbConnection;

module.exports = {
  connectToServer: function (callback) {
    client.connect(function (err, db) {
      if (err || !db) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      dbConnection = db.db("users");
      console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");

      return callback();
    });
  },

  getDb: function () {
    return dbConnection;
  },
};
```

Here the callback function **client.connect()** is deprecated since mongodb v5. So i used another package to support the legacy mongodb drivers from here:
[Legacy-Driver](https://github.com/mongodb-js/nodejs-mongodb-legacy)

That package on github says:

> The next major release of the driver (v5) will drop support for
> callbacks. This package will also have a major release at that time to
> update the dependency requirement to ^5.0.0. Users can expect to be
> able to upgrade to v5 adopting the changes and features shipped in
> that version while using this module to maintain any callback code
> they still need to work on migrating.

Lastly i changed the MongoClient location to this:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb-legacy");
```

Comment: Why not just use the new driver semantics?

Comment: @robertklep I guess the new driver semantics use async await. But i was following this doc to implement mongoDB on my project, which they haven't updated yet. https://www.mongodb.com/languages/express-mongodb-rest-api-tutorial.

Comment: The above doc is updated now.