# Unable to connect to localhost in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb installed in my PC. Some years ago, I created the databases and collection in `localhost` server before `1year`, but today I tried to connect it from MongoDB compass using the connection string,and it is being logged in successfully:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false
```

I want to connect it through the linux terminal,but searching on most of the post and docs I found the username and password is compulsory:

```
mongo mongodb://username:password@somewhere.mongolayer.com:10011/my_database
```

So,I am unware of what my username and password is, so I tried to connect it from terminal using:

```
mongo "mongodb://localhost:27118"

mongo --host localhost --port 27118
```

but I got error as:

```
2023-03-03T12:50:22.951+0545 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:27118, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

How can I connect to this localhost server from terminal?

Comment: Hi,
Where does your mongoDB run? Inside a docker container?

Comment: 1. Is the MongoDB server running?  2.  If it is running, is it listenning on port 27017 or port 27118?  3.  Is authorization enabled on the MongoDB server, i.e., is username/password required?

Comment: try to log the docker container, you can use docker logs -f 'container-name'

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881

Comment: Username/Password is only required when you enabled [authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-security.authorization). Anyway, error "couldn't connect to server" is not caused by missing credentials.