# i try to connect my mongoDB compass with node.js | same code can connect the mongoDB atlas but mongoDB could not connect

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, connection, ipv6

Error to connect the DB :  **MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017**
at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\MERN_INTERN\Demo Project\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\MERN_INTERN\Demo Project\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:730:11)

i try to connect the mongoDB compass with node.js

Comment: Basically main problem is with mongoDB server could not connect with IPV6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Comment: the mods would rather have answers deleted and make the people looking for answers wander around 100s of links than let them see the answer on whichever they found. No wonder newbies don't ask on SO anymore. They really hate newbies getting the solutions to their problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions I found by searching on Google to resolve this issue.

The main problem is with the **MongoDB server not being able to connect with IPV6**.

To resolve this issue you can do one of thee options:

**Option 1:**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test');
```

**Option 2:**

```
const connect = await mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING, {
            useNewUrlParser: true, 
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            family: 4,
        });
```