# unable to connect nodejs to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

I want to connect my node js to mongodb.
--> I am using mongodb version 6.5.0 (installed it as a service [complete install])
--> also I have installed mongosh (mongodb terminal)
--> I am able to access and modify my database using mongosh terminal (all commands are working in terminal)
--> In my project folder i first did "npm init", then "npm install node", then "npm install mongodb"(driver) & I am using nodeJS version 18.15.0
My code in "connect.js" file is as follows:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const DB_NAME = 'tododb';

// ASYNC IIFE

(async () =>{

   const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL)

   const tododb = client.db(DB_NAME)
   console.log(tododb)
   
})()
```

and I got this error when I do "node connect.js" in vs code terminal

```
C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\Gagan\DEV\mongoBasics\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:277
                const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\Gagan\DEV\mongoBasics\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:277:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1431144101,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\Gagan\DEV\mongoBasics\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:383:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\Gagan\DEV\mongoBasics\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:307:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

I want to use my nodeJS with mongoDB

Comment: const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'; try this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try It

Go to file manager and 1st stop and then start MongoDB

[image]

Replace your db URL `mongodb://localhost:27017` to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect by ipV6, the line `error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017` shows that; as suggested by @Muhammad Fazeel , change `MONGO_URL` to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`
This  explicitly starts connection through ipV4

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```js
const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
```

To:

```js
const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
```