# I still getting the same error : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Although I tried all suggested solutions in google?
But the same error keep popup to me.
**I checked my mongoDB server and  it's work fine.
I replaced localhost to 127.0.0.1 and also to 0.0.0.0
but it still not working.**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)