# My mongoose database is refusing to connect locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

I have been trying to connect my mongoose database locally to 27017 but it is refusing to connect.

I thought it might be an error in my code but all my other apps that I had previously built, that were fully functional and working before, have the same error when I try to run them.

I tried using the mongodb compass and running the mongod command in cmdm
but nothing seems to work.
What could be the reason for it?

I tried reinstalling mongodb but it didn't work as well.

This is the error output:

```
  \Desktop\rest-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\siddh\OneDrive\Desktop\rest-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\siddh\OneDrive\Desktop\rest-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:537:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:511:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 557344,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\siddh\OneDrive\Desktop\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\siddh\OneDrive\Desktop\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:512:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

This is my code:

```js
    import express from 'express';
    import { APP_PORT } from './config/index.js'; //We do not need to 
    const app = express();
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    
    
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/rest-api', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(()=>{
        console.log('Database connected');
    });
    
    
    app.listen(APP_PORT,()=>{console.log(`Server running on port ${APP_PORT}`)})
```

Comment: Please add the connection code in the question

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit alright I have edited it to add the error message and code as text now

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I did not really understand what I am supposed to do from the response in that question. Could please explain it again.

Comment: @AnveegSinha the connection string is present in the code now

Comment: Are you able to connect to mongo using the cmd terminal?

Comment: @AnveegSinha do you mean using the mongosh command and mongod command? If so, then yes I can view my databases using the command line but for some reason I cannot connect it to the localhost

Comment: What is  not clear in the answer where I provided the link?

Comment: Apparently in your operating system `localhost` resolved to the IPv6 address `::1`.  Did you configure your mongod to listen on `::1`?