# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 error

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongo-express

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

import mongoose from 'mongoose';

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/schooldb").then(() => {
    console.log("connection successfully ");
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello user')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening at port http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

Hii i am new to learn express , i am trying to connect my mongodb to express js, i am not able to understand this error
D:\Learn\Learn Express\ new_mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792
err = new ServerSelectionError();
^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\Learn\Learn Express\new_mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\Learn\Learn Express\new_mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11)
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) {
'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
address: 'localhost:27017',
type: 'Unknown',
hosts: [],
passives: [],
arbiters: [],
tags: {},
minWireVersion: 0,
maxWireVersion: 0,
roundTripTime: -1,
lastUpdateTime: 656213806,
lastWriteDate: 0,
error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at connectionFailureError (D:\Learn\Learn Express\new_mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
at Socket. (D:\Learn\Learn Express\new_mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 27017
},
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
},
topologyVersion: null,
setName: null,
setVersion: null,
electionId: null,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
primary: null,
me: null,
'$clusterTime': null
}
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}

i was expecting connection successfull message at console,please help me

Comment: It looks mongoose is unable to establish the connection. Please make sure your mongodb is running and the port is `27017`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 10):

In node.js v18, localhost uses ipv6 address (`::1`), and by default mongodb localhost doesn't have ipv6 enabled. That's why you're facing this issue.

If you want to use ipv4 localhost address (`127.0.0.1`),

1. **Either** replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/schooldb").then(() => {
    console.log("connection successfully ");
})
```

2. **OR** use `family: 4` parameter. This tells the node.js localhost to use ipv4 address.

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/schooldb",{
    family: 4,
}).then(() => {
    console.log("connection successfully ");
})
```

**OR**

If you want to use the ipv6 address, then just start `mongod` with `--ipv6` as argument. This enables mongodb ipv6 address.

```bash
mongod --ipv6
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I simply replaced the connection string from **'mongodb://localhost/MyDBName'** with **'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/MyDBName'**.
Also, please ensure that the MongoDB server is up and running.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

here mongodb trying to connect to the current system but it fails to connect because the database is not running on the current system to fix this use `0.0.0.0` instead of localhost.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/schooldb").then(() => {
    console.log("connection successfully ");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was on mongodb access permission and here's how I solve it

**Correct File Permissions**

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/log/mongodb
```

**Remove Incorrect Ownership**

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/collection-0--9070219476800958121.wt
```

**Start mongod**

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

**Check MongoDB Status**

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Comment: Despite your solution works, it has nothing do to with the asked question.

Answer (score -1):

In mac run in root terminal:

```
> brew tap mongodb/brew   
> brew install mongodb-community@7.0  
> brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
> mongosh
```