# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am beginner of nodejs.while doing the node js project i ran into the problem with connection error while connect with the mongodb. what i tried so far i attached below.
**MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017**

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
var routes = require('./route/routes');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors(
  {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080"
  }

));


app.listen(9991,function check(err)
{
    if(err)
    console.log("error")
    else
    console.log("started")
});



mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/gbs",{useNewUrlParser: true,  useUnifiedTopology: true },
function checkDb(error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("successfully Connected to DB");
    }
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);
```

Comment: Don't use `localhost`, use `127.0.0.1`

Comment: thanks problem soled

Comment: This solution would solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563265/14895056