# Creating a feedback system using HTML, JavaScript, and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wanted to create an employee feedback system which collects feedback and save it to my `MongoDB` database. Below are the codes of back-end and front-end. I encountered the following error:

> Failed to submit feedback. Please try again later.

The detailed error message is:

```
api/feedback:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
employee_feedback.html:71 Error: Error saving feedback.
```

This is a `Node.js` code which serves as the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Serve static files (HTML, CSS, JS)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Use express.json() to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.json());

// Connect to MongoDB (make sure to have MongoDB installed and running)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/feedbackDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err);
});

// Create a mongoose schema for feedback
const feedbackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
});

const Feedback = mongoose.model('Feedback', feedbackSchema);

// API endpoint to save feedback
app.post('/api/feedback', async (req, res) => {
    const feedbackText = req.body.text;

    if (!feedbackText) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Feedback text is required.' });
    }

    try {
        const newFeedback = new Feedback({
            text: feedbackText,
        });

        await newFeedback.save();
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Feedback saved successfully.' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving feedback to the database:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error saving feedback to the database.' });
    }
});

// Catch-all middleware for handling other routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'employee_feedback.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

```
The code for the front-end is below: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Employee Feedback System</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }

        form {
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }

        textarea, button {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #feedbackList {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Employee Feedback System</h1>

    <form id="feedbackForm">
        <label for="employeeFeedback">Provide your feedback:</label>
        <textarea id="employeeFeedback" rows="4" required></textarea>

        <button type="button" onclick="submitFeedback()">Submit Feedback</button>
    </form>

    <div id="feedbackList">
        <h2>Employee Feedback</h2>
        <ul id="feedbackData"></ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        function submitFeedback() {
            var feedbackText = document.getElementById('employeeFeedback').value;

            if (feedbackText) {
                // Send feedback to the server
                fetch('/api/feedback', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ text: feedbackText }),
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Error saving feedback.');
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    alert('Feedback submitted successfully.');
                    document.getElementById('employeeFeedback').value = '';
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error.message);
                    alert('Failed to submit feedback. Please try again later.');
                });
            } else {
                alert('Please provide feedback before submitting.');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the code from your front-end that makes the request. The `405 (Method Not Allowed)` suggests you are sending a POST request to a different endpoint from the one you think you are sending it to.

Comment: Your fetch request looks like it should work. Can you confirm if your `app.post('/api/feedback` route is matched. Just `console.log(feedbackText)` inside the route and check the terminal to see if your text was sent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `mongodb-Shell`, You need to change the connection string - `host` as `127.0.0.1:27017`.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/feedbackDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563265/14895056

If it doesn't work then update your question and add exactly what error you're getting. What i mean is show the output of this,

```
console.error('Error:', error.message);
```