# MongoDB doesn't not connect with "localhost"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost

Why does my MongoDB database connect using an URL that contains 127.0.0.1 instead of using 'localhost' as default, even though it doesn't work when I try to use 'localhost'?
Here's the error i get:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 79726509,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\...\connect.js:379:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\connect.js:285:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

I tried disabling the firewall for public and private networks, and it still doesn't work. The moment I replace 'localhost' in the URL i use in the code to connect to the database with the IP 127.0.0.1, the database seems to connect.

Comment: This happens because "*Node.js 18 and up prefer IPv6 addresses over IPv4 by default. And, most Linux and OSX machines have a ::1 localhost entry in /etc/hosts by default. That means that Node.js 18 will assume that localhost means the IPv6 ::1 address. And MongoDB doesn't accept IPv6 connections by default.*" https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html

Comment: You connect to localhost, the firewall does not apply for local connections.

Comment: Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017 does not provide solution for you question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an IPv6 issue. Most likely, `localhost` is initially parsed as an IPv6 address (::1), and node.js doesn't try again when that fails. When you specify the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1, the connection works on the first try.

Comment: I didn't think about that. Do you know any ways to fix? I mean other ways to solve it besides the one I'm using

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304154/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127017-error?rq=1), you can use `family: 4` to specify IPv4 addresses.