# How to connect mongodb database present in virtual machine using IP from another system

Tags: mongodb

How to connect the MongoDB database present in a virtual machine from another system or lap

I have a database created in the virtual machine. I want to connect to that database from my personal system using the IP of that Virtual machine.

Comment: Simply use the IP (the hostname would be even better) instead of `localhost` in the connection string. What did you try?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<IPaddress>:27017/customer_db   
 I was using the above in my Spring tool suite for connecting to mongo db compass .In place of IPadress i have given my system ip address. Before I was connecting llike this by giving localhost spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/customer_db..When i try connecting with my ip address getting the Following error.........Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ipaddress:27017 com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881