# Getting time out error in MongoDB 6.0.1 from quick start code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timeouterror

Here is the code bellow when I run it in mongohshell I am geting an time out error

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'fruitsDB';
const client = new MongoClient(url, {useNewUrlParser: true});

// Use connect method to connect to the server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  insertDocuments(db, function() {
    client.close();
  });
});
```

I changed the Url form 'mongodb://localhost:27017' to 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017' but it didn't worked

The comand line error shosw some thing like this

```
 const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                 ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Samse\all\Desktop\WebDevLearning\BackEnd\FruitsProj\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 3163819,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\Samse\all\Desktop\WebDevLearning\BackEnd\FruitsProj\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Samse\all\Desktop\WebDevLearning\BackEnd\FruitsProj\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is unable to connect to the mongodb. Chek your mongo is running and at port `27017`.

Comment: Is your MongoDB running?

Comment: Apart from check whether your MongoDB is running, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881