# I am trying to connect my mongodb server with node js app but its not working idk why even server mongod is running

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const assert = require("assert");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const dbName = "fruitsDB";
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(function (err) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("connected to the server");
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    client.close();
});
```

[image: image description]

This code should show in the terminal "connected to the server."

Comment: Seeing this come up a lot lately which means you should have been able to [find a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74610881/283366) by searching

Comment: you can use IP address instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `localhost` ip address for connecting to mongodb.
I don't know why but it was not working when i try to do with this url `"mongodb://localhost:27017"`

Go with this one

`use const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";`

Comment: Thanks bro changing the url solved the issue.