# MongoDB : Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a newcomer on this segment. I try to install mongodb on my computer, then its completed and added all bin path to the environment variable . I have tried to use mongodb in several ways, but I cannot solve the issue.

I have written this code and try to run, unfortunately it throws an error:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animals', (err, client) => {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log('works!!!!');
//   const db = client.db('animals')

//   db.collection('mammals').find().toArray((err, result) => {
//     if (err) throw err

//     console.log(result)
//   })
})
```

The error is :

```
PS D:\Nodejs Works\beginner works\mongo db works> node app
D:\Nodejs Works\beginner works\mongo db works\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278
                const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Nodejs Works\beginner works\mongo db works\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 7613188,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\Nodejs Works\beginner works\mongo db works\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Nodejs Works\beginner works\mongo db works\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Now, I can not understand, how to overcome from this problem, and connect with mongodb.

I think mongdb working on computer properly, because from task manager Services there I can see mongodb as running on background.

When I write in command line: mongosh, its give an output that is:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin> mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 64a6b08ac9697a1d4724af54
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
Using MongoDB:          6.0.7
Using Mongosh:          1.10.1

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

------
   The server generated these startup warnings when booting
   2023-07-06T16:19:36.122+06:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
------

test>
```

Then when I am writing 'mongod', its showing:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin> mongod

{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.670+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.673+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.673+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.675+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.675+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.675+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.675+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.676+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":10052,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-TAREQANNAN"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.676+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.677+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.7","gitVersion":"202ad4fda2618c652e35f5981ef2f903d8dd1f1a","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.677+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 25393)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.677+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.679+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:24.679+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3527M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.162+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":483}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.162+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.174+06:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.174+06:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.180+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.180+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5853300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"current featureCompatibilityVersion value","attr":{"featureCompatibilityVersion":"6.0","context":"startup"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.181+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.182+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.508+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.512+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.513+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.515+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T18:21:25.515+06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

My used versions of MongoDb and shell are:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin> mongosh --version
1.10.1
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin> mongod --version
db version v6.0.7
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.7",
    "gitVersion": "202ad4fda2618c652e35f5981ef2f903d8dd1f1a",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "windows",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sir. After I user that method, when I am giving mongosh command on terminal. I got new error message.
Current Mongosh Log ID: 64a6eba029b0ce6def6c2af5
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: That's strange, did you restart the mongod successfully?

Comment: Yes, I did. But still its not working. When I try to 'start' mongodb from Services. Its showing, - Windows could not start the mongodb server (MongoDB) service on local computer. Error 1053: The service didn't respond to start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: The have a look at the logfile