# Unable to Connect to MongoDB using Node.js MongoClient

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, firewall

I'm facing an issue while trying to connect to MongoDB from my Node.js application using the mongodb driver.

I have a MongoDB server running on my local machine, and I can successfully connect to it using MongoDB Compass and the VS Code extension.

However, when I attempt to connect from my Node.js application, I encounter an error.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

client.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');

  // ... continue with my code
});
```

The error message I receive is:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
  // rest of the error details...
```

I was try to connect to MongoDB from a Node.js app.

I have already checked the following:

- The MongoDB server is running on my local machine, and I can connect using MongoDB Compass and VS Code extension.
- I have installed the mongodb package using npm, and I tried different versions of the package as well.
- There is no authentication required to connect to my MongoDB server.
- I have also tried specifying the version of the mongodb package during installation, but the issue persists.

Why I can't connect to MongoDB from my Node.js application? Am I missing something in my code or configuration?

Comment: "_// rest of the error details..._" - missing info?

Comment: did u whitelist ur ip?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi everyone thank you all for your helpful comments,
the answer to this problem is in two steps

1. the localhost alias resolves to IPv6 address ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1,
   However, net.ipv6 defaults to false.
   the solution to this is to either

A. set them in mongod.conf file

```
  ipv6: true
  bindIpAll: true
```

or

```
  ipv6: true
  bindIp: localhost
```

B. just add them to the command when starting Mongo server

`mongod --bind_ip_all --ipv6`

2. I didn't have a mongod.conf file soo I had to write one,
   here is what it should look like

```
# mongod.conf

# Where to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\data\db

# IPv6 support.
net:
  ipv6: true
  bindIpAll: true

# Port to listen on (default is 27017).
# port: 27017

# Enable/disable journaling.
# storage:
#   journal:
#     enabled: true

# Set log files.
# systemLog:
#   destination: file
#   path: C:\data\log\mongod.log

# Replica Set Options.
# replication:
#   replSetName: "rs0"

# Authentication Options.
# security:
#   authorization: enabled

# More options and configurations can be added as needed.
```

the first two and are enabled the others are optional

also I would refer to this problem as it's like mine
[Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `localhost` in the URI by explicit locsl IPv4 `127.0.0.1`:

```js
const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';
```

As explained on [mongodb driver for Node](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#connect-to-mongodb):

> NOTE: Resolving DNS Connection issues
>
> Node.js 18 changed the default DNS resolution ordering from always prioritizing ipv4 to the ordering returned by the DNS provider. In some environments, this can result in `localhost` resolving to an ipv6 address instead of ipv4 and a consequent failure to connect to the server.
>
> This can be resolved by: [...]
>
> - using a host of `127.0.0.1` in place of localhost

Comment: thank you for your helpfull comment/answer 
the problem was not with ipv4 but something related to it