# How to connect local mongodb to a mern project

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern, dbconnection

I have started learn mern stack following a project on youtube. but I am keep getting the bellow error when connecting to mongodb

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGwwe.jpg)

[Connection to db (code snippet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HevG7.jpg)

Ensured that the MongoDB server is running using mongo shell and found no issues there.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.