# I am getting error in connecting to MongoDb database

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I tried to connect the database in this way, it was giving this error, while I have successfully connected the database like this before.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

exports.dbConnect = () => {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/cloudinaryEntry", {
        useNewUrlParser : true,
        useUnifiedTopology : true,
    })
    .then( () => console.log("Database connected successfully"))
    .catch( (error) => console.log("Error in connected database", error));
}
```

[Here is the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhJZb.png)

But when I added another attribute "family : 4 " then it get connected successfully.
***Can someone explain to me why it happened ?***

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
exports.dbConnect = () => {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/cloudinaryEntry", {
        useNewUrlParser : true,
        useUnifiedTopology : true,
        family : 4
    })
    .then( () => console.log("Database connected successfully"))
    .catch( (error) => console.log("Error in connected database", error));
}
```

**
[Here is the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXTKG.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Node.js driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver)

Answer (score 0):

As per the mongoose [faq](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html):

> The reason why this error happens is that Node.js 18 and up prefer IPv6 addresses over IPv4 by default. And, most Linux and OSX machines have a ::1 localhost entry in /etc/hosts by default. That means that Node.js 18 will assume that localhost means the IPv6 ::1 address. And MongoDB doesn't accept IPv6 connections by default.

The simplist resolution is to just to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in the connection.

The `{ family: 4 }` option you supplied is passed to the Node `dns.lookup()` function so that IPv4 is used. That's why it allows you to connect.