# My mongodb database is not getting connected with my express node server using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting started with backend and just keep  getting the same error.
This is my server.js -->

```
// Step 1 create a folder backend
// Step 2 npm init -y
// Step 3 open in VS Code
// Step 4 npm i express
// Step 5 create server.js

// Server Instantiate
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// used to parse req.body in express -> PUT or POST
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// Specifically parse JSON data and add it to the req.body object
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Server started on port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started at port no 3000");
});

// A get request for route '/'
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Jee Kaise hai aap");
});

// '/' route sends a response when accessed via GET
// This is a GET request --> app.get()

app.post("/cars", (req, res) => {
  const { name, brand } = req.body;
  console.log(name);
  console.log(brand);
  res.send("car submitted successfully");
});

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connection successful");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error came");
  });
```

Every time I am running this code in my terminal using "node server". I am getting the "error came" as output from .catch block .
Though my Mongodb server and express server is live but still I am unable to get connected with my database .
I am using Mongodb compass by the way. And the mongoose is also installed properly.

Please help me to come out from this error. I tried a lot but never getting "connection successful" as output.

Comment: `console.error(error)` would tell you a lot more about the problem

Comment: all seems ok, maybe try moving app.listen(//servercreation) to end of file. Also, clarify what eroor you are getting, share error

Comment: all i am getting is that catch block code

Comment: i am never getting "connection successful" and that means my server is not getting connected to database

Comment: Instead of `console.log("error came");` change it to `console.log("error came:", error);`. This will actually tell you what errror was thrown. At the minute all you are doing is logging your own message.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and guess it's probably a duplicate of this. [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Node.js driver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74609210/283366). Seems to trip up just about everybody these days

Answer (score -1):

try with node version 16 or which node you have currently

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

1. Check MongoDB Server: First, ensure that your MongoDB server is up and running
2. Check Mongoose Version : Required Latest Version
   use below command - `npm install mongoose@latest`
3. In your database make sure your network access is Allow access from anywhere

Database > Setting > Network Access

4. Check Network issues
5. Try to put database URL in below format

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.nig2yzc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score -1):

downgrade mongoose library version and which version you have currently