# Next.js TypeScript app fetch error with MongoDB – ECONNREFUSED ::1:59999

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, next.js, fetch-api

I encountered the problem when working on my Next.js TypeScript app that integrates with Prism MongoDB. While attempting to make a network request to MongoDB, I received a "TypeError: fetch failed" error, accompanied by an ECONNREFUSED error (::1:59999), indicating a failed connection attempt.

The difficulties I faced in solving this issue stem from the fact that there are various potential causes for this error, including MongoDB configuration, API server issues, network settings, and code-related problems. Identifying the exact source of the problem has proven challenging, and despite reviewing multiple aspects of my project and searching for solutions, I have been unable to resolve the issue on my own. Therefore, I am seeking assistance to pinpoint and rectify the root cause of the error.

I have encountered the "TypeError: fetch failed" error in my Next.js TypeScript app when trying to connect to MongoDB. To address this issue, I have taken the following steps:

1. **MongoDB Configuration**: I verified that my MongoDB server is running and correctly configured. The server is listening on the expected port (::1:59999), and my connection string is accurate. MongoDB itself appears to be functioning correctly.
2. **API Endpoint**: I checked the API server that my Next.js app is communicating with and confirmed that it is up and running. The API server does not seem to be experiencing any issues or downtime.
3. **Network Configuration**: I examined the network settings and firewall rules to ensure there are no restrictions or issues that might block the connection to the MongoDB server or API server.
4. **Environment Variables**: I double-checked my environment variables, ensuring they are correctly set and utilized in my code.
5. **Code Review**: I reviewed the code responsible for making the `fetch` request to MongoDB. I confirmed that the URL and port are correct, and any headers or request options are properly set.
6. **Error Handling**: I added error handling to the code to catch and handle errors when making fetch requests.
7. **Dependency Updates**: I ensured that all project dependencies, including Next.js and related libraries, are up to date, as updates can sometimes resolve compatibility issues.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm unable to establish a connection to MongoDB. The exact source of the problem remains elusive, and I am seeking assistance to pinpoint and resolve it. If needed, I can provide code snippets or specific error messages for a more detailed examination.

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver/74610881#74610881

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.