# can't connect mongodb to node-express using localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When i try to connect `mongoDB` with `nodejs` express using `post` method , where i just added a logger which will display a message database is connected if the nodejs listens to mongoDB , but i found that though the post menthod is working the Mongoclient is not working thus the logger is not working,first i tried using `(MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017)` but it resulted in showing `(MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017)` in the console,so i have replaced the localhost with `(MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')`.Now the result is is simply logging the console with the form inputs but still the app is not listening to mongoDB please help me out i'm totally a beginner

here is the code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient=require("mongodb").MongoClient
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.post('/',function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.body);
  next
})
router.post("/submit",function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.body);

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017',function(err,client){
    if(err)
      console.log('error')
    
    else
    console.log('database connected');
     client.db('bynode').collection("users").insertOne(req.body)
  })
  res.send("got it")
  
})

module.exports = router;
```

please help me iam stuck with my learning because of this
error

/*error*/
`F:\new space\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278 const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
^

> MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at Timeout._onTimeout (F:\new space\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
> reason: TopologyDescription {
> type: 'Unknown',
> servers: Map(1) {
> 'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
> address: 'localhost:27017',
> type: 'Unknown',
> hosts: [],
> passives: [],
> arbiters: [],
> tags: {},
> minWireVersion: 0,
> maxWireVersion: 0,
> roundTripTime: -1,
> lastUpdateTime: 24984871,
> lastWriteDate: 0,
> error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at connectionFailureError (F:\new space\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
> at Socket. (F:\new space\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
> [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
> errno: -4078,
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '::1',
> port: 27017
> }
> },
> topologyVersion: null,
> setName: null,
> setVersion: null,
> electionId: null,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
> primary: null,
> me: null,
> '$clusterTime': null
> }
> },
> stale: false,
> compatible: true,
> heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
> localThresholdMS: 15,
> setName: null,
> maxElectionId: null,
> maxSetVersion: null,
> commonWireVersion: 0,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
> },
> code: undefined,
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {},
> [cause]: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at connectionFailureError (F:\new space\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
> at Socket. (F:\new space\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
> [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
> errno: -4078,
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '::1',
> port: 27017
> }
> }
> }`

I tried changing the `MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017` to                          `MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017` the difference is that the error message of `(MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017)` was gone but still the node wasn't listening to mongoDB , i was expecting the logger will display that "database is connected" ,also the form inputs will be stored to databse in `bynode` in that a collection users.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver/74610881#74610881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code is working i tried it ..this question was posted by myself and i found its answer

`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb'); 
router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
  res.render('index',{title:express})
})
 
router.post('/submit', async function (req, res, next) { 
  try { 
    console.log(req.body); 
 
    const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"; 
    const dbName = "myDb"; 
    const client = new MongoClient(url); 
 
    await client.connect(); 
 
    console.log("Connected to the database"); 
    client.db("node").collection("users").insertOne(req.body)

    res.send("got it")

 
  } catch (error) { 
    console.error("An error occurred:", error); 
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error"); 
  } 
});

module.exports = router;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your client connection should exist outside of your request response and you're using outdated callback-style syntax. Mongo recommends you use ES Modules so that you have support for [top-level await](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-top-level-await/). There's a whole tutorial [here](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/express-mongodb-rest-api-tutorial).

```js
import express from 'express';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const router = express.Router();
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
await client.connect();

router.post("/submit", async (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body);
  await client.db('bynode').collection("users").insertOne(req.body);
  res.send("got it")  ;
})

export { router }
```

Comment: but in my codes had an  errorr and client parameters to perform a conditional statement,please give me a solution with the existing codes

Comment: gah, you're right, i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing name of the database in the connection string, You are providing localhost and port number in the connection string but you are not telling which collection the app should connect to.

try to put your collection name in you string like this,

```
'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/{your_collection_name}'
```

hopefully it should work.

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: You don't have to specify the database. If nothing is provided then it defaults to `test`