# MongoDB is not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

MY CODE IS:

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
    if(err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("school");
    dbo.createCollection("students",function(err,res){
        console.log("collection created!!!");
    });
    var myObjList=[
        {
            name:"rohit",
            age:15,
            gpa:4.9
        },
        {
            name:"rahul",
            age:17,
            gpa:4.7
        }
    ]
    dbo.collection("students").insertMany(myObjList,function(err,res){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(res);
        db.close();
    })
});
```

I want to insert datas to MongoDB storage but I failed to insert the datas to MongoDB storage.MongoDB connection is not estublished with this code. When I am trying to run the node js code but I am seeing this error in console:

```
const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                 ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 2471400,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {},
  [cause]: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
      at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
    [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 27017
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: does `0.0.0.0` work in a connection - I know what it means in a "listen" config, but I didn't think you could connect TO `0.0.0.0` - what error is thrown

Comment: Now I have tried  var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"; but this error is showing:- const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);

Comment: a) I can't read that, put it in the question, and b) is mongodb running on the same computer that the code is running on? is there perhaps a firewall preventing connection?

Comment: try `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

Comment: But this time also nothing is printed on console

Comment: what if you console.log the errors (as well as re-throwing them like you currently do) still no console output? I take it there's no authentication required on you mongodb instance?

Comment: According to the shown error message it should be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver/74610881#74610881

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Node.js driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver)

Comment: @JaromandaX there is no firewall when you connect to local machine.

Comment: @JaromandaX you can connect to a MongoDB without credentials even when authentication is enabled.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - cool