# Trouble connecting to MongoDB database and fetching data using Mongoose in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am currently learning how to connect to a MongoDB database using Mongoose in a Node.js application. Despite my efforts, I am encountering issues with the connection and data retrieval. The database I am working with is centered around books.

my code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const server = express();
const routeur = require("./routeur");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/biblio", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Defining the book schema
const livreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    nom: String,
    auteur: String,
    pages: Number
});

const livreModel = mongoose.model("Livre", livreSchema);

// Attempting to fetch data from the database
livreModel.find()
    .exec()
    .then(livres => {
        console.log(livres);
    })
    .catch();

server.use(morgan("dev"));
server.use(express.static("public"));
server.use("/", routeur);

server.listen(4000);
```

error:

```
(node:6876) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option...
(MongooseError: Operation livres.find() buffering timed out after 10000ms...)
```

I am using Node.js v18.17.1. The error suggests issues with the deprecated options and a timeout on the `livres.find()` operation. I expected to retrieve data from my database, but it seems there is a problem with the connection and data fetching. Can someone guide me in resolving this issue?

[image: image of my db]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't normally try to fetch database records outside of route handlers but if you just want to run a quick test to make sure you can run a successful query then you need to wait for the connection to be established first. Change to this:

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/biblio").then(()=>{
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
   // Test a database query
   livreModel.find({}).then(livres => {
      console.log(livres);
   });
});
```

Note the removal of `useNewUrlParser` and `useUnifiedTopology` options and addition of port `27017` to the connection.

Comment: hello @jQueeny , thank you for your help i was stuck since 3hours. Your code works. The connection got established when i changed 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1:27017. I really don't know why. Do you know the reason ?

Comment: You were missing the port number and Node.js 18 + prefers IPv6 addresses over IPv4 by default so localhost could have been resolving to `::1` @LionelSYMR

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver/74610881#74610881