# the mongodb docker container is not connecting

Tags: mongodb, mern

### Initial scenario

So I created a docker container for mongo db named blog_db

command `docker run --name blogs_db -d mongo`

### Commands tried

`docker ps`

#### Output

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                           NAMES
85dc17990758   mongo:7   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   35 hours ago   Up 48 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, 27017/tcp   blogs_db
```

### I didn't knew what to do

I searched a lot still no results.
I tried changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` still no improvement.

Comment: Looks like you run into this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver/74610881#74610881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What ended up working

I got it late after checking the logs and configs.
A bunch of yt videos and articles.

I tried connecting to other container of mongodb

```bash
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS         PORTS                                           NAMES
004611add127   mongo:7   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   passport-auth
```

It was working and then I noticed `:::27017->27017/tcp`

I got it `-p` was what I missed.
I thought since `27017` is the default port I do not need to write it.

But I was so wrong, it has to be there.
I spent a day trying to figure it out,
**deleted** the current instance
and created a fresh one with the `-p` and it worked.

***Take Backup before doing so***

```bash
docker cp blog_db:/data/db /path/to/backup/directory
```

then

```bash
docker stop blog_db
docker rm blog_db
```

```
docker run --name blog_db -p 27017:27017 -v blog_db_data:/data/db -d mongo
```

### Learning

```
Type your commands completely else you will have to debug it badly.
At times even debugging won't work.
```