# Due to that Mongose Error unable to run the backend

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.countDocuments()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\final year project\BiteBlitz\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
D:\final year project\BiteBlitz\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\final year project\BiteBlitz\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\final year project\BiteBlitz\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 276368947,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\final year project\BiteBlitz\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\final year project\BiteBlitz\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

The following error I'm getting.How to resolve it?

I tried connecting the mongodb again and the port as well but still it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Node.js driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver)