MongoDB Fails On Reboot - Socket Exception
I am having an error on boot. From what I've found, this error happens when trying to assign an IP that is not available on the local interface. I'm currently unable to post to mongodb community forum for some reason so I'm posting here, if this is the wrong place, feel free to inform me but I think it's acceptable as it's a software tool that's commonly used.
Device Information:
Raspberry Pi 5 using Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS
Specific Error:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-10T08:14:20.621-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"setup bind :: caused by :: Cannot assign requested address"}}}

Log File - Unable to upload file so hastebin is being used
Config File
Mongod.service file
I've ran the command ifconfig -a | grep "inet" and the output is as follows:
inet 192.168.1.214  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
inet6 fe80::2ecf:67ff:fe2e:a51e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>

I've removed the 192.168.1.214 portion of the bindIP, and it would start just fine after a reboot. I can manually start the service without issues with that IP (192.168.1.214, separated by the first IP with a comma) in the config file.
Edits

I recently discovered that I'm unable to connect VIA Mongo shell or MongoDB Compass unless I am tunneling VIA SSH, which was not the case before sometime last week


I would suggest to use bindIpAll: true instead of putting dedicated IP's

@WernfriedDomscheit Wouldn't that compromise security?

I've recently learned that I'm unable to connect to the db unless I am tunneling into it via SSH (learned this with MongoDB Compass and mongo shell), I will add this in the original post

I've been informed by mongodb community forum that I'm needing to find the service that initializes the local network interface//the specified IP

No, in principle you have only two settings. Use bindIp: localhost if you want to permit connections only from the current machine. Use bindIpAll: true to permit connections from remote computers (local machine is also included, of course). That's it, anything else does not make much sense, unless you have a machine with multiple network interfaces. However, MongoDB does not support multiple network interfaces, thus it does not make much sense either. I prefer localhost over 127.0.0.1 because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/74610881/3027266

@WernfriedDomscheit, thanks for that information; it clears things up quite a bit.

As @wernfrieddomscheit pointed out in this link, I did bindIpAll: true.

Solution:
As Wernfried Domscheit pointed out in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74610881/3027266, I did bindIpAll: true, which fixed the issue on boot.
In short, bindIp: localhost is used to allow connections from the machine only, and bindIpAll will allow remote connections.
