Strange : MongoDB Connection Failed: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
I have already gone through all the solutions provided for this issue and attempted to resolve it. However, everything seems to be working fine on my PC—MongoDB services are running without issues, and MongoDB Compass successfully connects to localhost. Despite this, I am encountering the following error while trying to connect through my Node.js application.


I am getting this error:
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
server is running on port 5000
error in conntecting with mongoDB MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Ankur PC Lenovo\backend Project ideas\blog-api\Blog-API-using-Node.js-\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Ankur PC Lenovo\backend Project ideas\blog-api\Blog-API-using-Node.js-\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:860:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:5)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:555:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:529:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

I tried to check all the services of MongoDB, MongoDB is showing connected.

So replacing localhost by 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 in the connect string, as suggested in the issue you're linking to, gave the exact same error?

Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-node-js-driver/74610881#74610881 The question you have checked has many wrong/poor answers. Be aware ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 is different to ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

@robertklep i tried all the way but still getting same error :(

This question has been answered many times, thus just the bullet points:

Check if your MongoDB (mongod or mongos) is installed and running
Check if you can connect with other tools, e.g. Mongo Compass or Mongo shell mongosh
Check carefully whether you use the same connection string in your code as in the other tool.
Verify that you have used the correct port (default 27017) in server config and connection string
Check localhost alias resolution and IPv4 vs. IPv6 binding (see Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Node.js driver)

