# MongoError: Econnrefused

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm just learning MongoDB and Node.js. I'm doing this really simple exercise from a video in which I try to connect my node.js app to my MongoDB, and I'm getting this error:

*{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }*

Before all that, I've configured a database on mongo, and have tested running some commands on terminal:

```
$mongod (everything ok)
$mongo (everything ok)
```

..and then I've created a database called 'products' and added some products to it. When I hit:

```
db.products.find()
```

It returns:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("55b2b27d7f9f84490b8a9170"),
  "name": "beer",
  "description": "belgian craft beer",
  "price": 20
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55b2b2c27f9f84490b8a9171"),
  "name": "whisky",
  "description": "scotch blended 18 years old",
  "price": 150
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55b2b3e47f9f84490b8a9172"),
  "name": "cachaça",
  "description": "typical brazilian cachaça",
  "price": 10
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55b2b4087f9f84490b8a9173"),
  "name": "water",
  "description": "water from the swiss alps",
  "price": 5
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55b2b2617f9f84490b8a916f"),
  "name": "wine",
  "description": "red porto wine",
  "price": 80,
  "tags": [
    "porto",
    "sweet",
    "wine"
  ]
}
```

**My app.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/products');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('Erro de conexao.', err)
});
db.on('open', function () {
    console.log('Conexão estabelecida.')
});
db.on('disconnected', function(err){
    console.log('Desconectado')
});
```

**And my package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "aula-mongoose",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "aula sobre mongoose",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node.js",
    "mongodb"
  ],
  "author": "Guga",
  "license": "WTFPL",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

I've read lots of posts about this, even threads here. But I couldn't find out what is wrong here.

**EDIT:**

Accidentally I tried to connect to $mongod while it was already running and I was prompted with this error:

*errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017*

So I changed this line in my app.js to:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/products');
```

And it worked. But I have no idea why. Anyone?

Comment: Possibly this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904991/mongodb-cant-connect-to-localhost-but-can-connect-to-localhosts-ip-address

Comment: see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37994794/3166417

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice work on finding the answer.

The issue was as you discovered, the port information was simply missing from the original statement of localhost.

When hosting dev servers on your local box, localhost will need port assignments.

Answer (score 3):

For others that that come and have an issue similar to this. Make sure that you read the installation notes for mongodb, especially the part of making sure that the folder /data/db exists in your computer. If it doesn't create it!

And if you still get an issue, try running:
`sudo mongod &` to make sure that mongo has the correct permissions to access the folder!